# URISyntaxException Illegal character in query

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to open a link in default browser. I have used the following code.

```
String myUrl = "http://www.example.com/engine/myProcessor.jsp?Type=A Type&Name=1100110&Char=!"; 

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(myUrl));
        } catch (IOException err) {
            setTxtOutput("Error: "+err.getMessage());
        } catch (URISyntaxException err) {      
            setTxtOutput("Error: "+err.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception err) {
            setTxtOutput("Error: "+err.getMessage());
        }
```

I am getting **URISyntaxException** Illegal character in query at index

I think this is because of characters such as **?**, **&** and **!** in my URL. I tried using:

```
URLEncoder.encode(myUrl, "UTF-8");
```

But this gives me another error.

```
Failed to open http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F........... 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please can you tell me how to correct the **URISyntaxException Illegal character** error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because of the whitespace here `...jsp?Type=A Type&...`, you can replace it with `+`

```
http://www.example.com/engine/myProcessor.jsp?Type=A+Type&Name=1100110&Char=!"
```

Answer (score 15):

You should not encode the whole URL because the URI class requires a valid protocol. Encode only the parameters

```
String params = URLEncoder.encode("Type=A Type&Name=1100110&Char=!", "UTF-8");
myUrl = "http://www.example.com/engine/myProcessor.jsp?" + params;
```

Comment: Actually just the values not the variable names and separators. Although the & separator may additionally need to be encoded depending upon where you are putting the URL, (ie in HTML or XML).  In the above case the issue happens to be the space character.

Comment: @Caleryn Right. That's the problem for the first `URISyntaxException`. For the second one, it's trying to encode the full URL.

Comment: `Encode only the parameters` I'm ashamed on how long it took me to find this phrase. I was going crazy trying to encode everything

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code snippet

```
public static String encode(String queryParameter) {
    try {
        String encodedQueryParameter = URLEncoder.encode(queryParameter, "UTF-8");
        return encodedQueryParameter;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return "Issue while encoding" + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather pass `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `"UTF-8"` to get rid of the `UnsupportedEncodingException`. By the way, `URLEncoder.encode()` accepts a charset since Java 10.

Answer (score 0):

The following code work for me:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
            params.add("filter", URLEncoder.encode(filter));

_webResource.path(MessageFormat.format(this._methodName,this._params))
                        .queryParams((MultivaluedMap<String, String>) this._params)
                        .type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .accept("application/json")
                        .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace spaces in URL with + like If url contains category=Adult Care then replace it with category=Adult+Care.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using any filter parameter then don't use space between the filter expression. Use %20 in place of the space. For example my filter is like this
_filter = Number_field eq 15
So this will not work in JMeter as there is space between the Number filed and eq
Use like this
_filter = Number_field%20eq%2015