# How to use getRequestUri().getRawQuery() in the url on Java escape

Tags: java, url, restful-url

As know url would not allow some special character there, so need encode for that:
: `metadata=[{name: serialnumber, value: aaaaaaaaa},{name: register, value: abcde}]` in the url

I tried this encode would work

```
String abc= java.net.URLEncoder.encode("http://localhost:9080/myapp/myapp/search?metadata=[{name: serialnumber, value: aaaaaaaaa},{name: register, value: abcde}]", "utf-8");
```

But why would be fail following if use **info.getRequestUri().getRawQuery()** instead?

```
public Response search(@Context final UriInfo info, @Context final HttpHeaders httpHeaders) throws Exception {
        String requestURI = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(info.getRequestUri().getRawQuery(), "utf-8");
```

error:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query
```

How can I encode this successfully if I will use **info.getRequestUri().getRawQuery()**

Comment: If you're programming in Java, why did you add the unrelated language tags for JavaScript and C?

Comment: Can you paste the exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the white space in metadata.
You may either -

1. Remove the white spaces (metadata=[{name:serialnumber,value:aaaaaaaaa},{name:register,value:abcde}]
2. replace white spaces with +
   as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574205/6863495)

Hope that work!

Comment: Thanks @Urvashi Soni,  I removed white space in metadata, but still not work for info.getRequestUri().getRawQuery(),  while this is work:  String abc= java.net.URLEncoder.encode("metadata=[{name:serialnumber,value:aaaaaaaaa},{name:register,value:abcde}", "utf-8");